# A problem about inscribed and circumscribed circles...

Tags: triangles, circles

**PROBLEM**

Let $ABC$ be a triangle with incenter $I$. The circumscribed circle of triangle $AIC$ cuts the line $BC$ at point $D$, and the circumscribed circle  of triangle $ABI$ cuts the line $BC$ at the point $E$. Show that $I$ is the center of the circumscribed circle of triangle $ADE$.

**DRAWING**

[image]

**MY IDEAS**

So, we can simply show that $AO_1IO_2$ is a rhombus. (idk if this is right)

If we want to show that  $I$ is the centre of the circumscribed circle we have to show that triangles $IED$, $AIE$ and $AID$ are isosceles, am I right?

I don't really have much ideas of how can I show those and I don't know if my idea is right. Can you help me ? I will give a bounty to the one who answers. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $I$ is the incentre of $\triangle ABC$, $\angle ICA=\angle ICD=\frac{\angle C}{2}$,
$\angle IBA=\angle IBE=\frac{\angle B}{2}$

$\angle IDE= \frac{\angle C}{2} + \angle DIC =\frac{\angle C}{2} + \theta$, let $\angle DIC=\theta$

Since $AIDC$ is a cyclic quadrilateral$\angle IAD = \angle ICD=\frac{\angle A}{2}-\theta=\frac{\angle C}{2}$ and $\angle DIC= \angle DAC=\theta $

$\angle IED= \frac{\angle B}{2} + \angle BIE =\frac{\angle B}{2} + \alpha$, let $\angle BIE=\alpha$

Since $AIEB$ is a cyclic quadrilateral$\angle IAE= \angle IBE==\frac{\angle A}{2}-\alpha=\frac{\angle B}{2}$ and $\angle BIE= \angle BAE=\alpha $

$\angle IED=\frac{\angle B}{2} + \alpha = \frac{\angle A}{2}=\frac{\angle C}{2} + \theta = \angle IED $ (exterior $\angle$ of $\triangle$)

then $IE=ID=IA$ (sides are $=$ opposite $= \angle's$)($\angle$'s are $=$ subtended same segment$)

Comment: Easier: $\angle ABI=\angle IBE=\frac12\angle B$ so equal angle subtends equal chord in the circle $AIEB$ gives $AI=IE$.  Similarly $AI=ID$.

Comment: @user10354138: yes the main idea is the using cyclic quadrilaterals $AIDC$ and $AIEB$ and properties of incenter that makes $\angle$ bisector

Comment: @LionHeart Thank you so much for your answer!

Comment: May i ask why at the end you said that $IE=ID$ and at the same time equal $IA$. I don't understand.

Comment: @Ionela Buciu : $\angle$'s are in same segment

Comment: @LionHeart Ooooo....I understand now. Thank you so much!

Comment: A similar issue : problem 4 in [USAMO 1988](https://artofproblemsolving.com/wiki/index.php/1988_USAMO_Problems/Problem_4)